# Really confused with object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

A project for my computer science class is being confusing, and I'm not entirely sure what's up with the objects.

I have to take data from this weather API, and that's all going well, but theres one part of the returned object that I can't access for some reason.

Here's the function I'm using to get the info, input is the city name inputted by the user. I removed a few bits, but only different variables like currentTemp that also responded correctly

```
function getCurrentWeather(input) {
    var APIKey = APIKEY;
    var queryURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + input + "&appid=" + APIKey;

    $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: "GET"
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);

      currentTemp = response.main.temp //THIS ONE WORKS
      currentWeather = response.weather.description; //THIS ONE DOESN'T

      alert(currentWeather);
    });
  }
});
```

Here's the console:

```
    Object {
  base: "stations",
  clouds: Object {
    all: 20
  },
  cod: 200,
  coord: Object {
    lat: 42.36,
    ion: -71.06
  },
  dt: 1588552126,
  id: 4930956,
  main: Object {
    feels_like: 288.63,
    humidity: 25,
    pressure: 1002,
    temp: 293.22,
    temp_max: 296.15,
    temp_min 290.37
  },
  name: "Boston",
  sys: Object {
    country: "US",
    id: 3486,
    sunrise: 1588498564,
    sunset: 1588549556,
    type: 1
  },
  timezone: -14400,
  visibility: 16093,
  weather: [Object {
  description: "few clouds",
  icon: "02n",
  id: 801,
  main: "Clouds"
}],
  wind: Object {
    deg: 280,
    speed: 3.6
  }
}
```

The weather object is in brackets for some reason, and It's formatted very strange. I am using Codepen, if that changes anything.

Comment: Object at weather is an array (based on the `[]` usage) with a single object. Try: `response.weather[0].description;`

Comment: typo error `temp_min 290.37`  => `:` is missing so `response.weather` can't be read

Comment: anything that follows this syntax error cannot be read by the json interpreter

Comment: No, no bug. I probably mistyped it, because my computer wouldn't let me copy and paste the console for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'weather' there is an array of objects with, at least in this case, a single object. You should be accessing it like this: `response.weather[0].description;` (if what you want is always the first object, hence the '0' index).